# Deleting the "Page title" module in an existing site that needs some module-removal (Will damage SEO?)

Tags: 7

A drupal 7 site owner asked me to clean all unnecessary modules in her site. After I've successfully updated all modules and DB, I went to start delete some modules.

I've deleted unused modules until I came across [Page title](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_title), the well known module from the Drupal 6 era, which it's functionality now a part of the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module. I wonder if deleting it will destroy the page titles that have already been added to the site's nodes... What is the technical truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page Title stores its titles in a DB table, which will be deleted (along with all its data) if you uninstall the module. It uses an HTML preprocess hook to load that data from the DB on a page-by-page basis, and replaces whatever would normally be the title for that page right at the last minute.

So...

> I wonder if deleting it will destroy the page titles that have already been added to the site's nodes

Is entirely accurate. If you remove the module, you'll also remove the page titles that were added using it, and Drupal will use whatever default title was applicable for the entity before you installed it in the first place (e.g. for nodes that'll be whatever is in the `title` property).

Comment: Clive, sorry for not asking this, but is there a comfortable way to move all of these page titles of each node into the Metatag module? So I could delete the module without losing these titles? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's built in to the metatag module luckily enough: https://www.drupal.org/node/1658970